# How to pass along Json without parsing in web api?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api based server.  All controller methods accept objects and return objects (parsed from/to json by the framework). This has been working fine.

However, due to a new requirement, I need to create an adapter and place it between clients and the server.  The adapter will be responsible for translation of a small subset of client messages before passing them to the server.

I'd like to avoid unnecessary deserialization/serialization from/to json of messages that do not need to be translated. That is, in majority of cases I'd like to pass raw json client requests to the server and raw json server replies to clients.

The controller methods that will do the translation will have 'standard' signatures - no problem here.  However, I'm not sure how to forward messages (json strings) from clients to the server (and vice versa) without deserialization and serialization.

Is this possible in ApiController?

Thanks.

Comment: read up on middleware. looks like a candidate based on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What criteria determines which messages need to be translated and which do not?

Comment: @BrianRogers If I can do it from a controller then it'll depend on a method of the controller - i.e. some methods will pass json strings to the server without any interpretation/parsing.  If I need to do earlier (e.g. in a filter) then it'll depend on a uri.